# Type error: undefined is not a function - Promise.all() error in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fetch the document ID's of all the users in my database.
For which I have written this code:

```js
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('every 2 minutes')
  .onRun(async context => {
    console.log('This will be run every 2 minutes!');
    try {
      const usersRef = await admin //Works Perfectly, I get the QuerySnapshot of the collection
        .firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .get();
      console.log('usersRef: ', usersRef);
      const userDocs = await Promise.all(usersRef); //This gives the error
      console.log('User Docs: ', userDocs);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err: ', err);
    }
    return null;
  });
```

I obtain this error on passing the QuerySnapshot promise in `Promise.all()`:

```
//Error
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at exports.scheduledFunction.functions.pubsub.schedule.onRun (/srv/index.js:624:38)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

I expected to collect all the document IDs from the result of `Promise.all()`

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try removing ```await```, which is in front of admin

Comment: @sathish1409 that would not make a difference

Comment: That will make the difference, You are just referencing the function Right?, Any it will await at ```Promise.all```

Comment: May I know what does ```console.log('usersRef: ', usersRef);``` returns

Comment: It returns the querySnapshot

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/ejvxa7/type_error_undefined_is_not_a_function_promiseall/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) takes an array of promises.  `usersRef` is neither an array, nor a promise.  Since you're already awaited the promise returned by get(), that makes `usersRef` a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object that's immediately available, so you will need to work with it on those terms.  Since it's a *snapshot* and *not a reference*, you should probably name it differently.  For example:

```
const usersSnapshot = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .get();

const usersDocs = usersSnapshot.docs
console.log(usersDocs)

usersSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `await Promise.all` is not needed, since you already load all user documents int the first statement with `get()` and `await`.

So it should be:

```
  const usersDocs = await admin 
    .firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .get();
  console.log('User Docs: ', userDocs);
```